# Unable to open Android Studio in macOS Catalina 10.15.7

Tags: macos, android-studio, flutter

The following message in being shown as soon as I open the IDE -

The IDE cannot create the directory.
Possible reason: parent directory is read-only or the user lacks necessary permissions.

If you have modified the 'idea.config.path' property, please make sure it is correct,
otherwise, please re-install the IDE.

---

Location: /Users/chinmay/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /Users/chinmay/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1

I have tried re installing the IDE, but same message is being shown to me.

Answer (score 1):

Version 4.1.x does not work on Mac OS catalina.
Downgrading to 4.0.x versions from here was my other option.
[AndroidDownloads](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive)